# Best free online resources to learn competitive programming

Tags: tips

I am quite proficient in C++ and Java and want to learn competitive programming to participate in contests like Google codejam and other online contests held on sites like CodeChef and Codeforces. I would like to get information about any **free** resources including websites and courses to learn the "sport". Book suggestions are also welcome.

Please suggest some courses which have some practical work included and not just flat theory. I want to work on my problem solving skills rather than just learning algorithms and data structures.

Comment: @a'_' I didn't get you. I mean that I don't even know how to solve algorithmic problems then how can I code golf. I want to know about some resources to learn so then maybe I could make a better use of those tips you are pointing to.

Comment: I mean, just try to solve any problem here. You will improve yourself as you solve them. Like, I assume you know how to write ["Hello, World"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world), right? Go ahead and post an answer! (You will eventually get used to these tips while you are posting answers.)

Comment: Hey there, while I understand your quest, I fear this is not the correct place to ask for help, as the _programming challenges and competitions_ held in this community differ wildly from what it looks like you want to do. Other than that, my best suggestion is to practice hard problems. In trying to solve problems you find hard, you end up learning a lot.

Comment: But trying to solve any hard problems without any previous knowledge would be like shooting with a blind eye. Won't it ?

Comment: Hey, one of the best learning resources is this one: https://train.usaco.org/usacogate - And after you understand basic algorithms, you will be able to understand more advanced books like "Algorithms" by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest. (You should ask this question on Quora)

Comment: Also, you can find all kinds of free code and resources on GitHub. Here is one collection I found: https://github.com/lnishan/awesome-competitive-programming

Comment: @AndriyMakukha, please don't answer off-topic questions in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

## Practice Algorithmic Thinking

If there's one thing I believe programmers need to master, it's the process of dissecting a problem statement and planning their approach.

By this, I mean having the ability to approach an unseen challenge and think about what is being asked.

If I were you, I'd look at challenges posted around this website, ranging from trivial to difficult, and take the time to plan how you would solve the problem. That way, you'll be able to have a hands on experience with problem solving.

Once you do this enough, start placing time restrictions on your thinking time. Because I know from personal experience that competitive programming is most often timed. Once you have got that nailed, you should be ready for competitions.

In summary: practice. Y'all need to walk before y'all can run. I hope to see you as an active contributor around here!

Comment: I don't think this website is a good place to practice in competitive programming. ICPC and IOI tasks never ask to solve a problem in as few bytes as possible.